# Can I unlock the Halloween Dungeon Defenders costumes using Open characters?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Dungeon Defenders just got some DLC that unlocks a few Halloween costumes when playing on TrendyNet.  Some others costumes appear to be unlockable via drops or somesuch.

Are any of these available when *not* playing on TrendyNet, and if so how do I get them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Halloween Content will be availiable on Open beginning November 5th.

Source: http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?10214-Hallowe-en-Content-Available-Forever&p=83406&viewfull=1#post83406